# trying to sort a array of arrays using php.. pulling hair out?

Tags: php, sorting

I am in the middle of doing a quick prototype of some statistical graphs using FLOT and php and I am literally hacking something together to show something.

However I am faced with a problem which is doing my nut...

so I have some data which I have grabbed from the database and then in order to make it work easily for my Flot hack I have converted it to look something like this:

[ [0,1], [2,1] , [4,1] , [4,1] , [5,1] ,[9 , 1] , [9, 1] , [10,1] , [12,1], [13,1] ]

now the end plan is to have several sets of data and then produce a stacked chart. so what i need to do is sort out where there are duplicate like in the above where there is:

[.....[4,1],[4,1] .....]

needs to look like this:

[.....[4,1],[4,2,1].....]

below is my attempt at trying to sort it ( it is the latest iteration of attempt i have tried forwards, backwards changing inner values and outer values)...

```
$count = count($array);
$sorted = false;
while (!$sorted)
{
    $doneSomething = 0;
    for($i = $count - 1; $i > 0; $i--)
    {
        $tempArr = $array[$i];
        foreach($array as $key => $a)
        {
            if($key == $i)
            {
                echo "breaking";
                continue;   
                }
            $result = array_diff($tempArr,$a);
            if(count($result) == 0 )
            {
                $array[$i][1]++;
                if(count($array[$i]) == 3)
                    $array[$i][2]++;
                else
                    $array[$i][] = 1;
                $doneSomething++;
                }
            if($doneSomething > 0)
                break;
            }
        }
    if($doneSomething == 0)
        $sorted=true;
    }
```

the result is this:

```
 Array
   (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 4
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 1
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 1
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 2
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 1
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [1] => 1
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => 13
            [1] => 1
        )

   )
```

As you can see not really my intended result:

[ [0,1], [2,1] , [4,1] , [4,2,1] , [5,1] ,[9,1] , [9,2,1] , [10,1] , [12,1], [13,1] ]

If anyone can help me resolve this issue it would be really appreciated.

thanks

Vade

Edit: i should note that if there is only 2 duplicates it isnt that bad i can work that out but its when there is 3 or more ie:

[....[4,1],[4,1],[4,1],[4,1]...]

which needs to look like:

[....[4,1],[4,2,1],[4,3,2],[4,4,3]....]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out. This seems to be working fine here:

```
<?php
    $array = array( array(0,1), array(2,1) , array(4,1) , 
                    array(4,1) , array(5,1) ,array(9 , 1) , 
                    array(9, 1) , array(10,1) , array(12,1), array(13,1) );

    $last_elem = null;
    foreach($array as &$elem){
        if($last_elem){
            if($elem[0] == $last_elem[0]){
                $elem[2] = (isset($last_elem[2]) ? $last_elem[2] + 1 : 1);
                $elem[1] = $last_elem[1] + 1;
            }
        }
        $last_elem = &$elem;
    }

    var_dump($array);
?>
```

This is working perfectly here, I have tested it with this array:
`[ [0,1], [2,1], [4,1], [4,1], [4,1], [4,1], [5,1], [9,1], [9,1] ,[9,1] ,[10,1] ,[12,1], [13,1] ];`

The output is:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => int 0
      1 => int 1
  1 => 
    array
      0 => int 2
      1 => int 1
  2 => 
    array
      0 => int 4
      1 => int 1
  3 => 
    array
      0 => int 4
      1 => int 2
      2 => int 1
  4 => 
    array
      0 => int 4
      1 => int 3
      2 => int 2
  5 => 
    array
      0 => int 4
      1 => int 4
      2 => int 3
  6 => 
    array
      0 => int 5
      1 => int 1
  7 => 
    array
      0 => int 9
      1 => int 1
  8 => 
    array
      0 => int 9
      1 => int 2
      2 => int 1
  9 => 
    array
      0 => int 9
      1 => int 3
      2 => int 2
  10 => 
    array
      0 => int 10
      1 => int 1
  11 => 
    array
      0 => int 12
      1 => int 1
  12 => &
    array
      0 => int 13
      1 => int 1
```